# Retrieved result is empty

Tags: node.js, sqlite, typeorm

I create a database with table `user_account` and the table has 2 records.

```
CREATE TABLE user_account 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    email TEXT, 
    login TEXT, 
    session_id TEXT NULL
);
```

[image]

Datasource

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { UserAccount } from "../entities/UserAccount";
import * as SQLite from 'sqlite3'

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "sqlite",
    database: "./inventory.db",
    //driver: SQLite,
    logging: false,
    synchronize: false,
    entities: [UserAccount]
})

AppDataSource.initialize()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Data Source has been initialized!")
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error during Data Source initialization", err)
    })
```

UserAccount class

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BaseEntity } from "typeorm";

@Entity({name: "user_account"})
export class UserAccount extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number=0;

    @Column()
    username: string = "";

    @Column()
    email: string = "";

    @Column()
    session_id: string = "";
}
```

LoginController

```
import { Response, Request, response } from 'express';
import { ErrorResponse } from '../utils/errorResponse';
import { AppDataSource } from '../db/data-source';
import { UserAccount } from '../entities/UserAccount';

const login = async (req:Request,res:Response,next:any) => {
    const {username,password} = req.body;
    
    const userRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(UserAccount);
    const meAndBearsPhoto = await userRepository.find();
    
    if (!username || !password){
        return next(new ErrorResponse("Please provide a valid username and Password", 400));
    };

    res.send(meAndBearsPhoto);
}
module.exports = {login}
```

index.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import express, { Express } from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

dotenv.config();

const app: Express = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3500;

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

//Built-in middleware for json
app.use(express.json());

//middleware for cookies
app.use(cookieParser());

//Route Middlewares
app.use("/api/auth", require("./src/routes/login"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`⚡️[server]: SAT is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

It should return 2 record, but instead it returns an empty array. I have tried other ways of querying (findOneBy) and I get the same result.

This is the query produced by TypeORM:

```
[1] query: SELECT "UserAccount"."id" AS "UserAccount_id", "UserAccount"."username" AS "UserAccount_username", "UserAccount"."email" AS "UserAccount_email", "UserAccount"."session_id" AS "UserAccount_session_id" FROM "user_account" "UserAccount"
```

This query works fine.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing arguments into the `userRepository.find(...)` function?

Comment: No, the find() should return all the data from the table.
See https://typeorm.io/ and this example
const photoRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Photo)
const allPhotos = await photoRepository.find()
console.log("All photos from the db: ", allPhotos)

Comment: You're certain there aren't any other `inventory.db` files on your filesystem?

Comment: Yes, there is, but on a different folder. The one I'm using is inside the project folder.

Comment: @dai based on your last comment about having more the one inventory DB, I just notice the file is created under the project root. Thats the reason I dont get any data back.
To my knowledge, I was thinking when I provide the DB on my datasource would be sufficient to access the data. But indeed another DB is created. This is not the behavior I was expecting.
At least the issue with empty data is now solved.